# Is it possible to make concentration ellipsoids for some groups in a dataset but not all?

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot my data by groups in a 3d plot using Rcmdr. However, some of my groups only have 1 data point, and therefore the ellipsoid function on Rcmdr wouldn't work for any other groups.

Here is my command:

```
scatter3d(x,y,z,point.col=as.numeric(Site), 
      residuals=F,surface.alpha=(0.0),group=(Site),
      ellipsoid=T, ellipsoid.alpha=(0.03))
```

This is the response I got from R

```
Error in chol.default(shape) : 
the leading minor of order 1 is not positive definite
In addition: Warning message:
In qf(level, dfn, dfd) : NaNs produced
```

I am just wondering if it is possible to still make the concentration ellipsoids for other groups with more than 1 data point?